# Handling dates and datetimes in ServiceStack's Ormlite

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, ormlite-servicestack

I am using `Ormlite.Oracle` to do something like this:

```
using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
            {
                var events = db.From<Event>()
                      .Where(row => row.Event_Date == Today);

                List<Event> results = db.Select(events);

                db.Close();
                return results;
            }
```

The issue is that `row.Event_Date` is a DateTime and `Today` is just a Date always ending in 00:00:00, so the where clause never matches. I would like to convert `row.Event_Date` to a Date. I've tried `Event_Date.Date`, and `Event_Date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy")` etc. But this doesn't work because OrmLite isn't translating these kinds of conversions very well to Oracle. For example, when I did `Event_Date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy")`, OrmLite translated this to a varchar(1000) cast in Oracle, but kind of forgot about passing the string format.

Is there any way to get around this without using raw sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add 1 day to Today and then use the && operator to select all Event_Date that have the correct date part without considering the time part

```
 var Tomorrow = Today.AddDays(1);
 var events = db.From<Event>()
                .Where(row => row.Event_Date >= Today &&
                              row.Event_Date < Tomorrow);
```

Comment: Interesting solution! I feel like I'd rather use raw sql instead of doing this, but this is a smart way to approach the problem

Comment: I don't know ormlite but it should convert that expression in the appropriate sql and if you have an index on that Event_Date column this should be really fast (And I suggest to forget string conversion when dealing with dates)

Comment: @jgozal Not sure why you'd drop down to raw SQL when you don't need to, but you can add a raw SQL condition in a OrmLite's SQL Expression with `q.Where("field = {0}", value)`

Comment: @mythz I would only do it because raw sql can be a bit more declarative than this

Comment: @jgozal I disagree, this is exactly how I'd do any range queries in C# as well.

Comment: @mythz precisely. With raw sql you wouldn't have a need for a range query. You would just do conversion and equality.

Comment: @jgozal You compare date ranges in C# using string format conversions?

Comment: @mythz  I don't understand your question. There is no need to compare date ranges - that is only a workaround to solving this without using raw sql. The problem at hand only requires me to compare 2 dates, one that is always ending in a 00:00:00 time, and another that is ending in an arbitrary time. If I convert the arbitrary time date to a 00:00:00 time format there is no need to implement range comparison.

Comment: Explicitly converting the arbitrary date to a 00:00:00 time format also better expresses the goal of the where clause which is to return an event that's happening today. With ranges it reads like "return a date between x and y" and the developer has to wonder for a second why you return a date between x and y when you just want to return today's events. It's less declarative.

Comment: @jgozal I'm aware you can use string format, I'm just surprised you would. Would you also use string formatting for queries comparing weekly/fortnightly/quarterly, etc? Just seems easier to always use the same expression for any date range. Also as Steve mentions there is a performance penalty for using string conversions which will invalidate any indexes it can use. (Note: formatting DateTime in general is also very expensive, even in .NET).

Comment: @mythz I won't disagree with the performance penalty. But in this case I'm pretty sure it would be unnoticeable, this is a very small application with very small queries.

Comment: @jgozal Not being able to use an index means it needs to do a full table scan which can be very expensive and would also need to pay the DateTime string format conversion cost for each row which for proper implementations can also be very expensive. Definitely not something you want to run on a large dataset, but yeah if dataset is small it's less of an issue.

Comment: @mythz, I will perform some benchmarks. Thanks for the insight.